# Clear all Selections with deselectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a tableview that allows multiple selections. When returning to the tableView I would like to clear all previous selections. The code below only clears the first selected cell. How can I clear all cells?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() != nil) {
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a tableviewcontroller?

Comment: @swiftshokunin yes, i'm using UITableViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `indexPathsForSelectedRows()` instead.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
        for indexPath in selectedRows {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath as NSIndexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using a `UITableViewController`, you can just set its property called `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `True` (like @swiftshokunin said).

References:

- [indexPathsForSelectedRows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForSelectedRows)
- [clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewController/clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear)

Comment: `indexPathsForSelectedRows()` still only clears the first selection. The `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` has the same issue in my comment for @swiftshokunin's answer. http://i.imgur.com/cYFNpvC.png

Comment: Are you looping through the values and deselecting each NSIndexPath?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I need to loop through all the selected values? Would I use a `For .. In ...` loop?

Comment: Exactly! I don't know Swift too much but I'will update my answer to something that could work.

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewController has a property:

```
clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear
```

[image]

Comment: I implemented it in the viewWillLoad and it doesn't have any affect. http://i.imgur.com/OQ62GSM.png

Comment: try willDidAppear or view